# trying to download plugin that supports mongodb source config configuration element

Tags: mongodb, plugins, download, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Already having jmeter-mongodb-plugin 0.4jar, jmeter plugins, jmeter plugins extras and standards in lib. kindly share the jar file that supports mongodb source config configuration element

Comment: Can you explain your question in brief?

Comment: Please show us some code of what you have tried. Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am trying to do performance testing in Jmeter using MongoDb collection attributes as input. For that, i tried implementing the steps in below link. i couldnt show any progress/coding since i am lagging in the step 1 requirement itself. could yu please refer the link below for which i am referring to https://www.blazemeter.com/ja/blog/how-load-test-mongodb-jmeter  It will be helpful if you can provide me the jar files that will add mongodb source config option to my test plan